# Extract variable's value from solve

Tags: ti-basic

I'm trying to write a function for a TI-Nspire cx cas calculator. I have to solve a large system, using the built-in `solve` function. I want to save the result of `solve` in some variables. For example, if the result is `u1=2 and u2=3`, I would like to store 2 and 3 respectively in the variables `u1` and `u2`. Does anyone know how to do this automatically in a program?

Comment: You can use `string(Solve(...))` to convert the output of `Solve` to a string, then do some intensive string handling (using `inString` looking for characters between `"="` and `" "`) to extract the numerical values and convert them to numbers using `expr`.  This is the only way I can think of doing it.  Sorry I don't have time at the moment to actually write the code, but I did check and `string` will convert the expression to a string.

Comment: In summary, there is no built-way way to do this

Answer (score 4):

Try exp▶list(Expr,Var) function. Example>

```
res:=solve({x+2*y=5,x-y=2},{x,y})
```

x=3 and y=1

```
l1:=exp▶list(res,{x,y})
```

[[3,1]]

Answer (score 0):

For linear equations you can simply use `linsolve()`:

```
linSolve(x=5 and y=x+5, x, y)
-> {5,10}
```

Very handy is the pipe character for accessing the variables of the output:

```
solve(x=5 and y=x+5, x, y)
-> x=5 and y=10

x|x=5 and y=10
-> 5
```

You can also store the value:

```
res:={x, y}|x=5 and y=10
```

Unfortunately that does not work with an `or` in the output of `solve`.

Comment: I'm here for the use of `and` along with `|` which drove me nuts for an hour. Thanks.